# jQuery Userlike Form Submit but No Page Change

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, encoding

I am trying to post a form but don't want the page to change.

There are many methods suggested on SO, but neither of them works for me.

I cannot use jQuery's ajax or post APIs because they both change the encoding while serialize and server show corrupted characters on page view.

I have to find a way that would let me post data as user was clicked the submit button. Is there a way of doing that?

Suggested usage, but not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#mySubmit").click( function (e) {
  $("#myGiswebForm").submit(function() {
   // Handle the submission
   return false;
  });        
 });   
});
```

Below usage prevents default click actions but not form actions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySubmit").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myGiswebForm").submit();       
 });   
});
```

This usage posts form but also goes to form's action page, which is not desired.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#mySubmit").click( function (e) {
  $("#myGiswebForm").submit();       
 });   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could disable the default acition of the button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySubmit").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myGiswebForm").submit();       
 });   
});
```

Edit : xy_'s hack

```
<form id="myGiswebForm" method="post" action="https://******/saveForm.asp" target="myiframe">
and add a 
<iframe style="display:none;" src="" name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: This prevents click actions but not prevents page change.

Comment: This still goes to page after click. // comment for your revision

Comment: Well after some research it wont work the way you want it , unless you use ajax..i will update you if i found something else..

Comment: Thanks Mostafa. Ajax method posts all Turkish characters corrupted.

Comment: you could add 'contentType' in your ajax request , its default is UTF-8 dunno why its working with Turkish , but you could try to play around with it , here jquery docs : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: contentType also didn't work I don't know why. Turkish characters would work if posted page encoded with UTF-8 but it is ISO-8859-9. So... Mostafa thanks for your help, I found a hack for that. I would accept your answer for thanks to your time. If I use `<form id="myGiswebForm" method="post" action="https://******/saveForm.asp" target="myiframe">` and add a `<iframe style="display:none;" src="" name="myiframe"></iframe>` it only reloads the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an almost identical issue and the jQuery core libs were, as you've noted, not helpful.  The jQuery Forms plugin is likely what you need: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: This didnt't post form, should I download the malsup script and make some configuration?

Comment: `$("#myGiswebForm").ajaxSubmit(function() { return false; });` this worked but with corrupted characters as jQuery's ajax API